# paintComponent() is not working when add to panel

Tags: java, swing, graphics, windows

I was working a swing application that can draw graphs of maths function. I was using getGraghics functions but I have no idea how I remove and repaint them so  I decided to override the paintComponent() method to implement what I was looking for

what I want to do is drawing function graphs in a panel after user click the button. but it seems paintCompnent() is not working. I have followed exactly on any existing tutorial and similar questions on stack overflow.but none of them working for me :( it just made no sense:(

Please help I have stuck on this problem for over a whole night:(

following were codes for drawing functions graphs but as it is not working so I only left the part of drawing coordinate system for testing and after that is the code of how I create an instance and try to add it to my panel in the main class

```
class drawfunction extends JPanel{


 @Override
 protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
     super.paintComponent(g);


     g.setColor(Color.red);
     g.drawLine(0, 200, 400, 200);
     g.drawLine(200,0 , 200, 400);


 }
```

}

then is the code in main class

```
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();



    panel.setBounds(14, 104, 400, 400);
    contentPane.add(panel);

    panel.setBackground(Color.white);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("View the graph");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {


           //a= Integer.parseInt(cofficient_a.getText());
           //b= Integer.parseInt(cofficient_b.getText());
           //c= Integer.parseInt(cofficient_c.getText());
           //d= Integer.parseInt(cofficient_d.getText());
           //e= Integer.parseInt(cofficient_e.getText());


        drawfunction a=new drawfunction();
        panel.add(a);



    });
```

Can anyone please tell me what I should do to fix this. Thank you !!!!

Comment: Well, two things, one - the default size of panel is `0x0` and two - Swing is lazy, you will need to call `revalidate` and `repaint` when you want to update the UI

Comment: Also, class names should start with an upper case character!

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have just tried to use setPreferredSize() to set the size of the panel and I have also tried to add these two function. now a small blank square will appear everytime I press the button.

Comment: @FortyIX I just did a runnable example, try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two basic things...

1. A component has a default preferred size of `0x0`, so when adding it a container under the control of just about any layout manager will get it sized to `0x0` (or very close)
2. Swing is generally lazy, it won't update the UI when you add or remove components, that could impede performance, as the UI doesn't know the best to update the UI based on what you are doing, instead, you need to call `revalidate` and (most of the time) `repaint` to have the UI updated

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JPanel center;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("View the graph");
            center = new JPanel();
            center.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
            add(center);
            btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                    remove(center);

                    //a= Integer.parseInt(cofficient_a.getText());
                    //b= Integer.parseInt(cofficient_b.getText());
                    //c= Integer.parseInt(cofficient_c.getText());
                    //d= Integer.parseInt(cofficient_d.getText());
                    //e= Integer.parseInt(cofficient_e.getText());
                    center = new Drawfunction();
                    add(center);
                    revalidate();
                    repaint();

                }

            });
            add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        }

        public class Drawfunction extends JPanel {

            public Drawfunction() {
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(400, 400);
            }

            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2d.setColor(Color.red);
                g2d.drawLine(0, 200, 400, 200);
                g2d.drawLine(200, 0, 200, 400);
                g2d.dispose();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: my UI was actually designed by the Windows Builder Pro and it did made the creation of Jframe of mine different to others. your code can be perfectly run thank you but mine still cannot though i have done what you said :(

Comment: Well, here's a nice new opportunity to ditch Window Builder and start building your UIs by hand, because the problem lies with using Window Builder